# Date format in Go

Tags: datetime, go

I need to format a Date.Time object which is a UTC string into the following format “dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS”. I need to loop through an array of transactions and alter the StatusDateTime for each transaction in the array.

I've tried the below while playing around with the format, but it does not alter the date format at all.

```
for _, Transaction := range Transactions {
        Transaction.StatusDateTime.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05")
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `StatusDateTime` is of type `time.Time` then you CANNOT "alter its format". `time.Time` is a struct type, its "format" is a set of unexported fields with specific names, types, order, these fields cannot and will not change any of the aforementioned attributes at runtime because Go is a *statically* (not dynamically) typed language.

Comment: `.Format` does not work "in-place", you'll need to assign the returned value to some variable

Comment: ah thank you! I'll need to change it to a string then, i must show this date in the prescribed way. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion in this question. Let me break it down.

> I need to format a Date.Time object which is a UTC string into the following format “dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS”.

First, I think you mean a `time.Time` object. There's no such thing as a `Date.Time` object in Go.

Second, a `time.Time` object is, well, an object (well, a struct instance anyway). It is *not* a "UTC string".  It's not a string at all!  It's an arbitrary value stored in memory.

Now, you're on the right track by calling the `Format` method of `time.Time`.  But as you can see by reading the [Godoc](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Format) for that method, it returns a string. Your code example ignores (and therefore discards) that return value.

You need to assign that value somewhere, then presumably do something with it:

```golang
for _, Transaction := range Transactions {
    formatted := Transaction.StatusDateTime.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05")
    fmt.Println("the formatted time is", formatted)
    /* Or store the formatted time somewhere, etc */
}
```

> I've tried the below while playing around with the format, but it does not alter the date format at all.

Not to beat a dead horse here, but you're right, this doesn't alter the format at all... Or more accurately, `time.Time` *has no format to alter* in the first place.